# make chart axis position low - vba

Tags: vba, excel

The default x-axis position of the charts made by vba are in the middle. How do I make the axis on the chart show up on the bottom?

my current code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("I3", Sheets("Main").Range("L3").End(xlDown).Address)
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
With ActiveChart.Parent
.Height = 400
.Width = 800
End With
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, setting the option manually and checking the code generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the TickLabelPosition property of your axis:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionLow
```